# XCode - How do you use storyboards and timed events

Tags: xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I haven't really used storyboards before but with a new client and iOS 5 I've decided to modernize myself. : D

With the app I am working on there is an initial splash screen, which would fade out after a set period of time (1 second) to the main view of the app. How do you represent that seque on a storyboard?

Thanks

Comment: iOS 5 != modernizing yourself :-) Sorry I cannot be more constructive, I have tried but had to runaway from storyboards. What you are asking for is really simple to do programmatically as I am sure you know.

Comment: Ouch on the snark. : DYep, I threw in the towel on this after about 10 minutes.